# Reduce height of DrawerHeader

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Currently the drawer header occupies a fixed height. How can I reduce the height of the drawer header to fit the content of its children?

```
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.account_box),
                Text(
                  'Name Here',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                ),
                Text('Email Here'),
              ]),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `DrawerHeader` this with a `Container` widget.

```
   Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 120,
              child: DrawerHeader(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.account_box),
                    Text(
                      'Name Here',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                    Text('Email Here'),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the header inside SizedBox or Container.
One suggestion: Wrap the header inside column, not in the list view because header should not be scrollable. Make listview the second child of column.

Comment: using listview inside column leads to render error, since these two widgets want all the height they can get... so listview inside column has no idea of its available height... do you have a suggestion how to fix this so that the column uses 100% of the available height?

Answer (score 0):

You wrap this with a Container widget

Container(
height: 140.0,

```
            child: DrawerHeader(

              child: Column(

                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [

                    Icon(Icons.account_box),

                    Text(

                      'Name Here',

                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,

                    ),

                    Text('Email Here'),

                  ]),

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue[300],
              ),
            )),
```